# Python - Memory leak when checking the size of a multiprocessing SyncManager Queue in a transient thread

Tags: python, memory-leaks, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

In a larger python program I noticed a memory leak relating to threading and checking the size of a [multiprocessing SyncManager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) Queue (perhaps other operations too?).

In the program a timed thread acts like a monitor and reports the size of the Queue (which we can then decide if additional workers need to be started etc...).

I have boiled down the code to the small script below that demonstrates the issue (with both python2 and python3).  From what I can tell, it seems that when the .qsize() call is made it must allocate some memory which then doesn't get cleaned up when that thread exits?

Is there an obvious flaw in my code or is this simply a case of "don't do this in a thread"?

I did notice the [Thread safety of proxies -- to protect with a lock.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) However I don't feel like this is really a case of that.

Here is the example program that exhibits the behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import threading
import resource
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager


def threadCheckSize():
    # apparently calling this in a thread that will soon be going away causes memory leaks?
    worker_queue.qsize()


manager = SyncManager()
manager.start()

worker_queue = manager.Queue()

print('Starting test!')

last_time = time.time() - 20
while True:
    if time.time() > last_time + 10:
        print('Memory usage: %s (kb)' % resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)
        last_time = time.time()

    my_timer = threading.Thread(target=threadCheckSize)
    my_timer.daemon = True
    my_timer.start()
    my_timer.join()
```